# Use button to expand div, then scroll the page to that div

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a div at the bottom of the page on every page of the site (footer). I have a button to expand that div, but I want it to also scroll the page down so that the user can actually see the expanded content.
Currently, I have:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#footerContent").on("hide.bs.collapse", function () {
        $(".btn").html('INFO <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>');
    });
    $("#footerContent").on("show.bs.collapse", function () {
        $(".btn").html('INFO <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
    });
});
```

```css
.btn-success, .btn-success:hover, .btn-success:active {
    color: #848484;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://able.thebrewroom.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#footerContent">INFO <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button>
<div id="footerContent" class="collapse">some content here</div>
```

Yes, I know, this is poor UX, which I have tried to explain to the designer, but they want to do it anyway. I just want the button to expand the DIV, and then for the page to scroll down so that I can actually see the content. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a scrollTo function in think, check out the below link they've used it in a innovative way in the example section,

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/